# update UI component from bean jsf

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

I want to update UI component from bean .

after click on button and fetch event then update UI component from bean(like inputtext).

how to update UI component from bean ?

Comment: This question is unanswerable without more context

Answer (score 0):

You can use **render** attribute in ajax call.

```
<h:inputText id="field" value="#{bean.fieldValue}">

<f:ajax execute="@form" render="field" listener="#{controller.yourMethod}" />
```